# Why is function slot in PyQt4 connect() `not defined`?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I'm simply trying to connect a button signal to the `button_clicked()` method. The contents of a QTextEdit object should be cleared when I click a button.

```
class App:
    def window(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        main_win = QWidget()
        main_win.show()

        self.disp_txt = QTextEdit(main_win)
        self.disp_txt.setText('hello world')
        self.disp_txt.show()

        button = QPushButton(main_win)
        button.show()
        QObject.connect(button,SIGNAL("clicked()"),button_clicked) <---exact spelling

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def button_clicked(self): <---exact spelling
        self.disp_txt.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = App()
    a.window()
```

I get error from `QObject.connect`'s argument: `NameError: name button_clicked is not defined`. I'm new to object-oriented programming and I'm not even sure if structure of my class is proper.

Comment: I strongly advise you to use the [new-style signal-slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). This would allow you to do `button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)`, which is much clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. The argument should be `self.button_clicked` for it to work. Solved my little problem although I'm still working on understanding these `self` semantics.